# Inserting a complete sentence between commas

Tags: commas

Following is an excerpt from [an NYT article](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/06/20/arts/television/ebon-moss-bachrach-the-bear-season-2.html):

> On a long walk around the waterfront near his Brooklyn apartment one recent afternoon, Moss-Bachrach greeted many neighbors. He’s been in the same airy, art book-filled loft — a fourth-floor walk-up — with his wife, the visual artist Yelena Yemchuk, and their two daughters, now 16 and 12, for over a decade; the couple’s unsleek vintage bikes are parked outside. In head-to-toe denim and hiking boots, his vibe is so quintessentially thoughtful Brooklyn dad — he bikes to the beach! He bakes bread and gives it away by the loaf! — that it verges, **he acknowledged laughingly**, on cliché.

What's the usage of the inserted sentence? Can a sentence be inserted without a conjunction as such?

Comment: This has been well answered already.  The passage spreads so much literary jam on the bread of the satire that I had to reread a couple of parts twice over to be sure I had understood.  But that is a matter of style, not grammar.

Comment: With or without the optional adverbial element *(**laughingly**)*, the utterance ***He acknowledged*** isn't really capable of being used as a standalone "sentence". Just as ***He said***, such constructions can only really occur within the context of associated text telling us ***what*** was acknowledged or said.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, such expressions as ***he said, she replied*** or your ***he acknowledged laughingly*** are used after quotations. So you would have:

> "In head-to-toe denim and hiking boots, his vibe is so quintessentially thoughtful Brooklyn dad — he bikes to the beach! He bakes bread and gives it away by the loaf! — that it verges", ***he acknowledged laughingly,*** "on cliché".

But in free writing the author does not have to conform to standard rules so the quotes are omitted.

Yes, it is grammatical to use such statements without a conjunction. It is a parenthetical used by the author to distance the author's voice from the voice of the character. The author is saying, this is what my character thinks, matters are looked at from their point of view, not mine.

It is called ***attribution***, as it attributes words, thoughts, etc. to *their actual source*. And [in this article on Grammarmonster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/verbs-of-attribution.htm) you will find *acknowledge* on the list of *verbs of attribution.*

Here is how [Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/reporting-clause-1691911#:%7E:text=Attribution%20also%20called%20a%20reporting,source%20and%20the%20appropriate%20verb.) defines *attribution*:

> ***Attribution*** also called ***a reporting clause*** in academia, is *the identification of the speaker or source* of written material. It is commonly expressed in words like "she said," "he shouted" or "he asks" or the name of the source and the appropriate verb. Sometimes this attribution ***identifies the tone*** as well as who made the statement. Both direct and indirect quotes require attribution.

Comment: Probably best to reserve 'reporting' for the reported equivalent of direct speech/quotes. << He said that he was sick >>: a report structure with a report verb. << He said "I am sick" >> a quote structure with a quotative verb. 'Say' can fulfil either role (needing a complementiser in report structures).

Answer (score 5):

"he acknowledged laughingly" is not a proper sentence, even though it consists of a subject and predicate. If it were said on its own, it would not make sense -- "acknowledge" is a transitive verb, it needs an object to specify *what* it acknowledges.

In your sample text, it's being used parenthetically, and the object is the surrounding sentence: "it verges ... on the cliché". The commas are used to set off the parenthetical modifier; this is a stylistic choice, one can also use dashes or parentheses.